# Can you help to understand how to use JOIN with spring-repository?

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa

I want to understand how to use JOIN with JPA-spring-repositories.
There are two tables Man and Car

```
Man
varchar(25) manId primary key not null
varchar(25) name
varchar(25) surname
varchar(25) modelCar

Car
varchar(25) carId primary key not null,
varchar(25) color,
varchar(25) model;
```

And visualisation:

```
    Man
    mainId   name     surname   modelCar
    =====================================
    111-1    Natasha  Smith     reno-123
    111-2    Maria    John      mazda-214


    Car
    carId      color     model
    ============================
    as-aw    red       reno-123
    os-dz    black     mazda-214
    sa-aa    yeallow   porche-1
```

Relation is one-to-one

My entities are

```
@Entity
@Table
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor 
class ManRecord{
   private String manId;
   private String surname;
   private String modelCar;
}

@Entity
@Table
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
class CarRecord{
   private String carId;
   private String color;
   private String model;
}
```

So, I need to write JPA-repositories to execute result of join:
name, surname and car-color:

```
select m.name, m.surname, c.color from Man m left join Car c on m.modelCar=c.model;
```

Can you help me with it?

I tried to

```
@Repository
public interface ManRepository extends CrudRepository<Man, String>{
   @Query("select m.name, m.surname, c.color from Man m left join Car c on m.modelCar=c.model", nativeQuery=true)
   List<Object> agregateData();
}
```

but I don't want to get just Object.

and, i tried someone with @OneToOne, but it doesn't help to for me

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not a good idea to join these entities through a model of the `car` - each `man` can have any cars so this join is not representative. The best way is to add a `r_man_id` into a `Car` table. It'll allow you to identify a car's owner.
After that you can add a unidirectional `@OneToMany` relation between them:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor 
class ManRecord{

    @JoinColumn(name = "r_man_id", referencedColumnName = "manId")
    private List<CarRecord> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    private String manId;
    private String surname;
    private String modelCar;
}

@Entity
@Table
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
class CarRecord{
    private String carId;
    private String color;
    @Column(name="r_man_id")
    private Long refManId;
    private String model;   
}
```

Then create a model that you need:

```
class ManWithCarObject {
    String name;
    String surename;
    String color;

    /**
    * Default
    **/
    public ManWithCarObject(){      
    }

    public ManWithCarObject(String name, String surename, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surename = surename;
        this.color = color;
    }

    // other methods
}
```

And the repo then will be:

```
@Repository
public interface ManRepository extends CrudRepository<Man, String>{
   @Query("select new com.contoso.model.ManWithCarObject(m.name, m.surename, m_c.color) from ManRecord m inner join m.cars m_c where m.manId = m_c.refManId")
   List<ManWithCarObject> agregateData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I need @OneToOne becase I viewed just only example table and I have couple external tables in other application database.

Comment: do I need to add @Id to any fields or new id?

Comment: `@id` must be added only for an identity columns, not for all

Comment: speaking of @oneToOne - for the case it's definitely is not the option due to my explanation in the start of the answer - no guarantee that won't appear another car for the given man

Comment: @Query("select new com.contoso.model.ManWithCarObject(m.name, m.surename, m_c.color) from ManRecord m inner join m.cars m_c where m.manId = m_c.refManId")
   List<ManWithCarObject> agregateData();

returns Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type ManWithCarObject

Comment: make classes public but not package-private. I think that Spring can't see the model

Comment: cheked it, my pojo is public